# T-SQL to Group time interval change by date range in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, window-functions

The original table has the column Timestamp with Interval

Interval: difference in minute between the current and previous Timestamp when sorted by Timestamp itself

```
Timestamp               Interval(InMinute)
2016-12-31 00:28:00     NULL
2016-12-31 00:29:00     1
2016-12-31 00:30:00     1
2016-12-31 00:45:00     15
2016-12-31 01:00:00     15
2016-12-31 01:15:00     15
2016-12-31 01:16:00     1
2016-12-31 01:17:00     1
2016-12-31 01:18:00     1
2016-12-31 01:19:00     1
```

I want to detect a time interval change using T-SQL and produce the output

```
StartDate                EndDate                Interval
2016-12-31 00:28:00      2016-12-31 00:30:00    1
2016-12-31 00:30:00      2016-12-31 01:15:00    15
2016-12-31 01:15:00      2016-12-31 01:19:00    1
```

I wanted to tell for how long an Interval stayed the same. The second row says that from `2016-12-31 00:30:00` to `2016-12-31 01:15:00`, the Interval stayed the same i.e. 15. But then it changed back to 1 after `2016-12-31 01:15:00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is an example , from Itzik Ben Gan (Gaps and Islands in Sequences)
This is base on this article: [Gaps](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions)

```
DECLARE @vt_Source AS TABLE
( ts datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 interval tinyint NULL
)

INSERT INTO @vt_Source(ts, interval)
VALUES('2016-12-31 00:28:00',     NULL)
,('2016-12-31 00:29:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 00:30:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 00:45:00'  ,   15)
,('2016-12-31 01:00:00'  ,   15)
,('2016-12-31 01:15:00'  ,   15)
,('2016-12-31 01:16:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 01:17:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 01:18:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 01:19:00'  ,   1)


SELECT
   min(ts_prev) AS startDate
  ,max(ts) AS endDate
  ,interval
FROM
   (SELECT
         ts
         ,interval
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ts ASC) AS  rn_all
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY interval ORDER BY ts ASC) AS rn_group
         ,LAG(ts,1,ts) OVER(ORDER BY ts ASC) AS ts_prev
    FROM
        @vt_Source
   )A
WHERE
   A.interval IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
   rn_all - rn_group
   ,interval
ORDER BY 
   startDate ASC
```

output for this:

```
startDate           endDate          interval
31/12/2016 00:28:00 31/12/2016 00:30:00 1
31/12/2016 00:30:00 31/12/2016 01:15:00 15
31/12/2016 01:15:00 31/12/2016 01:19:00 1
```

I added a `WHERE` clause to eliminate the first row , the one that have `NULL` on interval column

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=fe1888d0a934d73de0ed9887aaf4d482

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher, you can also use the [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) function.

The `LEAD` will get the value of the column in the next record, based upon the `PARTITION BY` and the `ORDER BY` in the function. Within this data-set, we are not partitioning on anything, but ordering it on the `ts` value.

Using the temporary table in the other answer, give this a try:

```
DECLARE @vt_Source AS TABLE
( ts datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 interval tinyint NULL
)

INSERT INTO @vt_Source(ts, interval)
VALUES('2016-12-31 00:28:00',     NULL)
,('2016-12-31 00:29:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 00:30:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 00:45:00'  ,   15)
,('2016-12-31 01:00:00'  ,   15)
,('2016-12-31 01:15:00'  ,   15)
,('2016-12-31 01:16:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 01:17:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 01:18:00'  ,   1)
,('2016-12-31 01:19:00'  ,   1)


;WITH NextInterval AS (
    SELECT 
        vs.ts
        ,vs.interval
        ,LEAD(vs.interval,1) OVER(ORDER BY vs.ts) AS next_interval
    FROM @vt_Source AS vs
    )
SELECT
    ni.ts
    ,ni.next_interval AS interval
FROM NextInterval AS ni
WHERE ni.next_interval IS NOT NULL
AND ni.next_interval <> ISNULL(ni.interval,0)
ORDER BY ni.ts
```